# How can I run a build including tests in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, running Build -> Make does a build and checks for compilation errors in the main tree, but not test trees. So if there was a compilation error in a unit test or UI test, it would not be found and the build would show as successful. How can I run a build across the whole project including test classes, without actually running the tests?

Comment: Have a look at the Gradle tool window in Android Studio. Should be at the top right.
Under `Tasks/build` there will be various tasks named according to your modules and flavours.  in my project they are named `compileDebugUnitTestSources`, `compileDebugAndroidTestSources`. This should be what you're looking for

Comment: @IvanWooll Thanks, the task list was not populated due to some setting "Only include test tasks in the Gradle task list generated during Gradle sync" which is turned on by default. I ran `gradle task` to get the task list and then got the values for my setup for those two tasks you mention, and eventually it worked.